# Running two jenkins servers projects on one shared node

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, sikuli

Data:

- different projects built on 2 different Jenkins servers
- one shared node with two slave agents run

Problem:
How to make the node 'busy' while one Jenkins is using the node? So far it is possible to run builds on both Jenkins at once...

Answer (score 0):

You could set the number of executors to 1. That would force Jenkins to run only one job on the machine. But if you've got non-Sikuli jobs, they'll also block (and be blocked by) your Sikuli jobs.

You could also declare one Sikuli job to be downstream of the other, and then there's an option to block on upstream/downstream jobs.

To do exactly what you're asking, I think you'd need a Jenkins plugin, and I don't know of an existing one that would help you.

Comment: I set number of executors to 1 already. Unfortunately that works only if I run these jobs on one jenkins (one domain), but I have two different Jenkins - both of them have specified node which point to the same computer.

Comment: @Robert that seems like a bad idea. Why would you want two masters and one slave? Does Jenkins even claim you can do this? I'd be very worried that running two slaves on one host would clobber files.

Comment: Also, since you are running two Jenkins masters: no there is no reasonable way for them to pass information between the two masters. Only terrible, terrible kludges.

Comment: it works quite good. We are running sikuli tests on the same machine, we have two slaves run at the same time and there is no problem. Configurations of slaves point to different directories so files are not getting clobbered.